# Views Accordion to be accessible by keyboard

Tags: 7, views, navigation

I need the [Views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion) module in Drupal 7 and what is in it to be accessible by the keyboard. When you are tabbing, it skips it completely. Also the screen reader does not recognize the closed items.

Anything I can modify to achieve this?

Comment: what does your markup look like? if you use <a> to toggle your accordion content, it will be tabbable (is that a word?!).

Comment: @jdu Sadly [not](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tabbable?s=t). But I use it all the time too ;)

Comment: Hi, i dont understand about using the <a> to toggle your accordion content.  what does that mean?

Comment: Hi, I can see that the views is putting an a href tag in the accordian header objects but still the tab does not get there. it looks like this :a href="#how_to_become_a_grantee-block-0" tabindex="-1">

Comment: so there are two problems that I see, one is that tabindex is -1 .  How do I get rid of that? also the ahref anchor goes to a content that doesnt exist in the source

Answer (score 1):

iput this in a block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('a')  

 .each(function(){ // loop through all matched elements

  $(this).removeAttr("tabindex");  

}); 

});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accordion is not accessible because it uses an extremely old version of Jquery UI that is included in Drupal core. The latest version of JqueryUI fixes several accessibility [issues](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9407).

You need to

- Install the v3 series of [Jquery update module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update). Unfortunately the jquery update module has at the moment still a very old version of JQueryUI (but there are [some issues working on it](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update/issues/2939759))
- Until jquery update offers a recent version of JQueryUI you need to patch the module so you connect to the CDN of the latest JQueryUI version, see [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update/issues/2197249): in jquery_update.module around line 529, just change the number of the latest version you want to use (see https://code.jquery.com/ui/). Depending on what of JQueryUI you are using you might also [take an older version if you have issues](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update/issues/2197249#comment-12053941).

  ```
   case 'google':
     $cdn = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui' . $min . '.js';
     ...............

   case 'microsoft':
     $cdn = '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui' . $min . '.js';
     ...............

   case 'jquery':
     $cdn = '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui' . $min . '.js';
     ...............
  ```
- Then go to /admin/config/development/jquery_update and select to use the CDN
- Clear caches